# Changing commas within quotes

Tags: c#, split

I am trying to read the data in a text file which is separated by commas. My problem, is that one of my data pieces has a comma within it. An example of what the text file looks like is:

```
a, b, "c, d", e, f.
```

I want to be able to take the comma between `c` and `d` and change it to a semicolon so that I can still use the `string.Split()` method.

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
 {
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine ()) != null) {
    bool firstQuote = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < line.Length; i++) 
    {
      if (line [i] == '"' ) 
      {
         firstQuote = true;
      }  
      else if (firstQuote == true) 
      {
         if (line [i] == '"')
         {
            break;
         } 
         if ((line [i] == ',')) 
         {
            line = line.Substring (0, i) + ";" + line.Substring (i + 1, (line.Length - 1) - i);
         }
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine (line);
 }
```

I am having a problem. Instead of producing

```
a, b, "c; d", e, f
```

it is producing

```
a, b, "c; d"; e; f
```

It is replacing all of the following commas with semicolons instead of just the comma in the quotes. Can anybody help me fix my existing code?

Comment: what about a regex match / replace ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically if you find a closing `"` you recognize it as it was an opening quote.

Change the line:

```
firstQuote = true;
```

to

```
firstQuote = !firstQuote;
```

and it should work.

Comment: Wow, so simple! I went over this at least 100 times and I didn't catch that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset firstquote to false after you hit the second quote.

```
                    else if (firstQuote == true) {
                        if (line [i] == '"') {
                            firstquote = false;
                            break;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple application to get the required result

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String str = "a,b,\"c,d\",e,f,\"g,h\",i,j,k,l,\"m,n,o\"";
        int firstQuoteIndex = 0;
        int secodQuoteIndex = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        bool iteration = false;

        //String manipulation
        //if count is even then count/2 is the number of pairs of double quotes we are having
        //so we have to traverse count/2 times.
        int count = str.Count(s => s.Equals('"'));
        if (count >= 2)
        {
            firstQuoteIndex = str.IndexOf("\"");
            for (int i = 0; i < count / 2; i++)
            {
                if (iteration)
                {
                    firstQuoteIndex = str.IndexOf("\"", firstQuoteIndex + 1);
                }
                secodQuoteIndex = str.IndexOf("\"", firstQuoteIndex + 1);
                string temp = str.Substring(firstQuoteIndex + 1, secodQuoteIndex - (firstQuoteIndex + 1));                    
                firstQuoteIndex = secodQuoteIndex + 1;
                if (count / 2 > 1)
                    iteration = true;                    
                string temp2= temp.Replace(',', ';');
                str = str.Replace(temp, temp2);
                Console.WriteLine(temp);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Please feel free to ask in case of doubt

Answer (score 0):

```
    string line = "a,b,mc,dm,e,f,mk,lm,g,h";

    string result =replacestr(line, 'm', ',', ';');


    public string replacestr(string line,char seperator,char oldchr,char newchr)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char chr in line)
        {
            if (cnt == 1 && chr == seperator)
            {
                b[b.ToString().LastIndexOf(oldchr)] = newchr;
                b.Append(chr);
                cnt = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (chr == seperator)
                    cnt = 1;
                b.Append(chr);
            }
        }
        return b.ToString();
    }
```